# Android PackageManager enable any application

Tags: android, package-managers

I have developed an application in which I have enabled that any application which we have can be installed manually

But my problem is that I only want to enable my own package name and rather not any other application package name.

Here is the code I have used.

```
try {
    PackageManager pm1 = getPackageManager();

    pm1.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName("com.service",
    "com.service.EnableActivity"),
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
    );
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

here "com.service" is the package name that I install and "com.service.EnableActivity" is my first app launcherActivity.

**Log**

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: attempt to change component state from pid=3354, uid=10056, package uid=10058 at
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322) at
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276) at
android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.setComponentEnabledSettingIPackageManager.java:2217)
```

But when I use the same application packagename and classname then it's working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Add this code in your both applications mainfest.

```
<manifest
  .......
  .......
  .......
  android:sharedUserLable="...."
  android:sharedUserID="...">
```

because it need a userid to be same

This will help you.

Comment: How its work. I want to make other application disable by my application but its give me crash. Permission Denial: attempt to change component state from pid=30188, uid=10472, package uid=10091

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the platform I see the following:

```
<!-- Allows an application to change whether an application component (other than its own) is
     enabled or not. -->
<permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE"
    android:label="@string/permlab_changeComponentState"
    android:description="@string/permdesc_changeComponentState"
    android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem" />
```

Note that because this is "signatureOrSystem" (and it is declared in the system) it can only be used by apps that are signed with the system signature, in other words you need to be an Android vendor (HTC, Samsung, Motorola, etc). See this for more info:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html

**UPDATE:**

Gurjinder Singh Pabla has the right answer, if you are trying to change the enabled state of your own components or applications then you need to ensure that they have the same user id, which is set in the AndroidManifest. You only need to be a Vendor if you want to disable other packages that have different user ids. You can see the check in the Android source in PackageManagerService.java is:

```
final int uid = Binder.getCallingUid();
final int permission = mContext.checkCallingPermission(
            android.Manifest.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE);
final boolean allowedByPermission = (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

// ...

if (!allowedByPermission && (uid != pkgSetting.userId)) {
    throw new SecurityException(
        "Permission Denial: attempt to change component state from pid="
        + Binder.getCallingPid()
        + ", uid=" + uid + ", package uid=" + pkgSetting.userId);
}
```

Comment: "Note that because this is "signatureOrSystem" it can only be used by apps that are signed _with the system signature_" - really ? Read the link you posted

Comment: I've updated the answer, I believe I am still correct, because it is declared in the system this particular permission is only available to the system or packages signed with the system key.

Comment: True - adding it results in an error - Well _it does not answer the question then_ - what good is it if you have to be a vendor ? Are you sure there is no way to change even one of _your other apps_ components enabled state ?

Comment: Sorry obviously I missed the point, you can change your own enabled states Gurjinder Singh Pabla has the best answer.

Comment: you can also get a mdm license from some mdm provider or directly from for example samsung. dev licenses are free.

this is the actual real reason why so many package disablers that _actually_ work cost at least a dollar.

Comment: How its work. I want to make other application disable by my application but its give me crash. Permission Denial: attempt to change component state from pid=30188, uid=10472, package uid=10091