# How to stop BroadcastReceiver manually in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have registered my `BroadcastReceiver` in `AndroidManifest.xml` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <activity android:name=".WiFiDemo" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.example.WiFiScanReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"> </uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

I want to stop this `BroadcastReceiver` using other application input how to stop this receiver programmatically ?

here is my receiver code:

```
public class WIFIBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction()
                .equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
            Intent ssIntent = new Intent(context, com.Activity.class);
            ssIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(ssIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

**Answer::**
I have add sharedprefernce checkbox and save the two string and validate in on receive method 
 here is my code

second application :

```
final CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager()
        .findPreference("checkboxPref");
// ...
checkboxPref
        .setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                    Object newValue) {
                if (newValue.toString().equals("true")) {
                    // String value = sp.getString(key, null);
                    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(
                            PREFS_READ, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                    Editor prefsPrivateEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    prefsPrivateEditor.putString(KEY_READ1, "true");
                    prefsPrivateEditor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "CB: " + "true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(
                            PREFS_READ, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                    Editor prefsPrivateEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    prefsPrivateEditor.putString(KEY_READ1, "false");
                    prefsPrivateEditor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "CB: " + "false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

validating code in first application inside of `onReceive` method:

```
public class WIFIBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction()
                .equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
            sharedPreferences = otherAppsContext.getSharedPreferences(
                    PREFS_READ, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            String scaningAction = sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_READ1, null);
            if (scaningAction.equals("true")) {
                Intent ssIntent = new Intent(context, com.Activity.class);
                ssIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(ssIntent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is my need. But I am not able to unregister the broadcast receiver. with out activity any this answer will helpful for some one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this :

```
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, myReceiver.class);

PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)
```

For more information visit [here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/manifest-receivers.html).

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(WiFiScanReceiver,
                            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: how to create WiFiScanReceiver object?

Comment: This is your brodcast receiver you build before (in code you attached)

Comment: Dont forget to enable it back again when the application starts back up or the onReceive wont get called

Answer (score 0):

Mostly you have to register your BroadCastReceiver in your `onResume()` method as it is the `Running State` of Activity. And we can unregister it inside the  `onPause()` which is `Stopped State` of an Activity. You can read more about it from [`Broadcast Receivers`](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449390501/Android_Broadcast_Receivers.html)

Comment: you can keep a boolean in SharedPreferences and check the condition inside the onReceive() `if(isTrue){ // execute receiver code}`

Comment: if true means how to unregister with out activity?

Comment: It means when you want to unregister your BroadCastReceiver you can assign false in your SharedPreference boolean variable, so the code inside `onReceive()` won't execute.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the code with the preference is in some preference activity. So leave your receiver as it was originally and use something like :

```
public class YourSettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    OnPreferenceChangeListener onPreferenceChangeListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        onPreferenceChangeListener = new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                    Object newValue) {
                if (newValue instanceof Boolean) {
                    final boolean enable = (Boolean) newValue;
                    PackageManager pacman = getPackageManager();
                    final ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
                            "com.example.yourapp1", WIFIBroadcastReceiver.class);
                    final int state = (enable) ? PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED
                            : PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED;
                    pacman.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, state,
                            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CB: " + enable,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        final CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager()
                .findPreference("checkboxPref");
        checkboxPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(onPreferenceChangeListener);
    }
}
```

You will probably run into security exceptions - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12697667/281545) for adding permissions :

```
<!-- Allows an application to change whether an application component (other than
      its own) is enabled or not. -->
<permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE"
    android:label="@string/permlab_changeComponentState"
    android:description="@string/permdesc_changeComponentState"
    android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem" />
```

Also you will have to be careful in line :

```
final ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
                            "com.example.yourapp1", WIFIBroadcastReceiver.class);
```

Post back if this solved it